# Why is it not showing my label?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I am new to swing, can anyone help me out with this...

It is not showing my "label" , instead it shows me only components which are in the "panel" class.

One more question, can anyone clarify me about LayoutManagers ?
Can 2 or more LayoutManagers be used in a frame ? like for the frame i will be using FlowLayout and i have a JPanel added to the frame for which i will be using BoxLayout ... is it possible in the first place ??

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class JForm1 extends JFrame
{
    public JForm1()
    {
        init();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JForm1 form = new JForm1();
    }
    public void init()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Form 1");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your Name : ");
        panel MyPanel = new panel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(MyPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JButton submitButton;
    JTextField text;
    panel()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        text = new JTextField("Enter Name here");
        text.setSize(100,25);
        submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.setSize(50,90);
        submitButton.setBounds(200, 0, 80, 80);
        submitButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(text);
        this.add(submitButton);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource()==submitButton)
        {
            System.out.println("The Entered Name is : "+text.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is this ?:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    text = new JTextField("Enter Name here");
    text.setSize(100,25);
    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    submitButton.setSize(50,90);
    submitButton.setBounds(200, 0, 80, 80);
    submitButton.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(text);
    this.add(submitButton);
}
```

This code has nothing to do in `paintComponent`. `paintComponent` is about "painting a component", ie, paint a rectangle, draw a line, fill an oval, etc... This is absolutely not the place where to add your components. Instead, call that code in your constructor.

Additionally, if you are using LayoutManager's (which you should), calling `setSize/setBounds/setLocation` is useless (dimply remove those calls).

A few more things:

- If you override `paintComponent`, make sure to invoke the `super`-method
- Don't extends `JFrame` if not needed (here it is clearly not needed)
- Follow Java naming conventions (class names should start with an UpperCase letter, variables and methods with a lowerCase letter)
- All Swing-related code must be called on the EDT. Start your UI within a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` block.

Comment: Are there any standards for Java like as for ANSI C ? If any can you please tell me those or tell me where i can find them ?

Comment: @Ravitheja Here is the list of conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html and in particular the naming conventions (with examples): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing layout to FlowLayout for mypanel.

```
mypanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Comment: changed it in the Constructor itself but no use. even after changing to FlowLayout there's no change in the appearence

Comment: try frame.getContentPane().setLayout().(new FlowLayout());